# How to remove text but keep the shadow

Tags: html, image, css

I want to make a background image for some text, and was looking around but I didn't find any easy answer. So I had an idea, what if I made a text shadow, and kept the shadow, but removed the text! heres the code i have:

CSS:

```
span{
    color: white;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #FFF, 1px -1px 0 #FFF, 1px 1px 0 #FFF, -1px -1px 0 #FFF;
    font-size: 200;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

HTML

```
<span>HELLO</span>
```

I want to make the HELLO invisible but keep the shadow so i have a text outline. the picture could then shine through. any ideas? any feed back is welcome!

Comment: create a div with your background image than use z-index:-1; to her and // span z-index:1;

Comment: Is [this](http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/svg/cut-out.html) the sort of thing you're looking for, or do you want text outlines against a background image (which, in SVG, would actually be easier)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give only the letters `0` opacity:

```
color: transparent; /* IE */
color: rgba(0,0,0,0); /* CSS3 */
```

Note the IE fallback since [IE8 and older doesn't support `rgba`](http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/).

---

#### DEMO:

JS used to toggle class for sake of demo.

```js
var el = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
setInterval(function(){
  el.classList.toggle('shadowOnly');
}, 500);
```

```css
body{ background: #000; }
span{
    color: #FFF;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #FFF, 1px -1px 0 #FFF, 1px 1px 0 #FFF, -1px -1px 0 #FFF;
    font-size: 200;
    opacity: 1;
}
span.shadowOnly{
    color: transparent; /* IE */
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0); /* CSS3 */
}
```

```html
<span>HELLO</span>
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as setting the color to white?

Comment: I am on FF mac, it looks the exact same http://jsfiddle.net/jL55hwjb/. Oh you are right, not the exact same, but very close

Comment: @Huangism I updated the demo to toggle the class every 500ms. That will make the difference more noticeable.

Comment: I think Huangism is looking for a 'cut out' effect, so the inner part of the shadow is not visible.

Comment: This is not what OP asked for. `I want to make a background image for some text, and was looking around but I didn't find any easy answer. So I had an idea, what if I made a text shadow, and kept the shadow, but removed the text`

Comment: What you did is a Mostel neon :D

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I read "I want to make the HELLO invisible but keep the shadow so i have a text outline." That's what I did.

Comment: The shadow in your example is of the whole text, it is not just an outline.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the text transparent:

```css
span{
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #FFF, 1px -1px 0 #FFF, 1px 1px 0 #FFF, -1px -1px 0 #FFF;
    font-size: 200;
}
```

PS: This should be more compatible than using rgba() colors.

Comment: Yeah I agree that color:transparent (which goes back to IE 4) will be better for this than rgba, but you should include both.

Comment: I wouldn't include rgba too, as transparent should be supported by the larger browser base and it won't have any positive effects. On the other side someone might cet confused about reading two definitions and not all browsers will fallback nicely with rgba colors (see http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/). Anyway we are talking about quite extreme edge cases here.